# submit form after given return false

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I want to submit a form after I prevented it from submitting.
I've seen some questions here on StackOverflow but none worked for me.

Here's the code:

```
$(function(){
    $("#loginform").submit(function(){
      var username = $("#user").val();
      $.get( "go.php?action=check_username&username=" + username  )
        .done(function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.indexOf("ok") >= 0) {$("#loginform").submit();}
            else {alert("Username doesn't exist");}
      })            
        return false;
    });
});
```

If the username exists it just runs the ajax again and again, never submitting the form.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @PranavRam it won't change anything , it is not exit point from function on submit.

Answer (score 5):

Your problem is that you have over-written the $("#loginform").submit();  - so even when you try and submit it from your javascript code you will then come back into the same function again.

Instead overwrite the button click/return pressed/etc events and do your comparison on that rather than on the loginform submit. Now you can submit the form yourself after performing the check.

The way I would actually do this is to start with the submit button disabled and put a listener for the text changing in the various fields. Validate each field as it is entered by listening for changes in that field and display a tick (or whatever) if they are valid.

Then once every field is valid enable the submit button.

Comment: I thought about it, but it takes up a lot of lines of code (well maybe not a lot, but quite a few) and it seems like this should have a simple solution.

Comment: I just added some more details on a possible approach. That uses no more code than your current one, you just listen to different events and enable the submit button rather than submitting the form yourself.

Comment: Why not have a 'click' event on the 'submit' button for the form instead? Then submit the form when the username is correct?

Comment: You have then to intercept enter keys on form elements e.g.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative solution

```
$(function(){
    var my_submit_allowed = false;
    $("#loginform").submit(function(){
      if (my_submit_allowed) return true;
      var username = $("#user").val();
      $.get( "go.php?action=check_username&username=" + username  )
        .done(function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.indexOf("ok") >= 0) {
              my_submit_allowed=true;
              $("#loginform").submit();
            }
            else {alert("Username doesn't exist");}
        })            
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: My Javascript is still somewhat lacking, but couldn't you just make that `var my_submit_allowed = false;`, since the same (local) variable will then be closed into both callback functions?

Answer (score 0):

I think in this case the jQuery method *.off()* could prove useful. Consider the snippet below. It feels a bit hackish, but it is also clear and direct:

```
$('#theForm').submit(function () {
    $.when().then(function () {
        $('#theForm').off('submit').submit();
    });

    return false;
});
```

Also, the official API examples for *.submit()* demonstrate how it can be quite flexible - https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery, and if you have a button to click in order to submit the form, you can unbind and rebind the submit event on your submit button

```
if (true) {
    $('#submitButton').unbind('submit').bind('submit');
} else {
    $('#loginform').on('submit', function(){
        return false;
    })
}
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$(function(){
    $("#loginform").submit(function(){
      var username = $("#user").val();
      $.get( "go.php?action=check_username&username=" + username  )
        .done(function( data ) {
            console.log(data);
            if (data.indexOf("ok") >= 0) {
              return true;
            }
            else {alert("שגיאה בהתחברות");}
      })            
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here, returning true from an async callback won't make anything submit.

Answer (score -3):

I have made few changes to the code. I have added retval as TRUE and checking at each state if retval is FALSE. If its FALSE, IT won't submit else if should submit as normal.

```
$(function(){
        $("#loginform").submit(function(){
          var username = $("#user").val();
          var retval = true;
          $.get( "go.php?action=check_username&username=" + username  )
            .done(function( data ) {
                console.log(data);
                if (data.indexOf("ok") >= 0) {
                    $("#loginform").submit();
                    retval = true;
                } else {
                    alert("Username doesn't exist");
                    retval = false;
                }

            /* If retval is EQ is FALSE then stop submit else if should submit as normal */
                if(!retval){
                    return false;
                }
          });          
        });
    });
```

Comment: You too return true from function on successfull `get` result, not on submit. Won't work.